# Trying to iterate "rem = (rem*value)%N" e times while saving each value of rem for i+1 and returning rem when i=e

Tags: javascript, encryption, elliptic-curve

So essentially I'm trying to make a function that takes an ASCII value and multiplies it by the remainder of the previous multiplication in the iteration.

So for the first iteration (i = 0), the remainder just gets set as the initial asc value. The second iteration (i = 1), the calculation is something like `rem = (rem * ascVal)%N`, where `rem` in `rem * ascVal` is the rem (remainder) from the previous iteration. 
This continues until i = e where the last value of `rem` is returned.

This is what i have so far:

```js
function newVal(ascVal) {
    var i = 0;
    var rem = ascVal;
    while (i < e) {
        rem = (rem * ascVal) % N;
        i++;
        if (i == e) {
            return rem;
        }
    }
    newVal(rem);
}
```

The thing is it always returns 55 if the input is a single value every time.
All i need it to do is find the remainder after `e` iterations. Any help would be great and i can post the entire script if needed (includes all calculations etc.)

P.S. This script is a small prototype elliptic curve encrypter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it by using a while loop.

```
function newVal(ascVal) {
var num = Number(ascVal);
var rem = num;
var i = 0;
while (i < e) {
    i++;
    rem = (rem*num)%N;
}
return rem;
```

}

This iterates the correct value each time.